# How to debug an Android app force close error?

Tags: java, android, xml, forceclose

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText oETextN;
EditText oETextPh;
Button oButtonSave;
public String givenName;
public String givenPhNum;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    findViewsById();
    oButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view){
            givenName = oETextN.getText().toString();
            givenPhNum = oETextPh.getText().toString();
            OrgiOperations.Insert2Contacts(getApplicationContext(),
                    givenName, givenPhNum);
            if (OrgiOperations.isTheNumberExistsinContacts(
                    getApplicationContext(), givenPhNum)) {
                Log.i(OrgiOperations.TAG, "Exists");
            } else {
                Log.i(OrgiOperations.TAG, "Not Exists");
            }

        }

    });

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

private  void findViewsById(){
    oButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
    oETextN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FLName);
    oETextPh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ph);

    //oEText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I've been trying to make a simple Android app that saves the entered details (Name and Phone Number) directly to your device phonebook. This is the MAIN activity, the other class includes the functions to do this, which I'm sure are implemented correctly.

The problem rises when I run the application on my phone, and unluckily after hours of cold coding I get the FORCE CLOSE error!

Comment: Hours? What happened to your logs?

Comment: `findViewsById` should be called after `setContentView`

Answer (score 3):

Change to

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
 initializeViews();
```

Then

```
  private  void initializeViews(){
    oButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
    oETextN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FLName);
    oETextPh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ph);
    //oEText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Name); 
  }
```

You need to set the content of the layout first to the activity then initialize views.

Also rename  `findViewsById();` to `initializeViews()` or something more appropriate coz you initialize your views with `findViewById` as `oButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);`

Edit:

Have the click listener after initialization of view.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
 oButtonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
 oETextN = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.FLName);
 oETextPh = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Ph);
    oButtonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view){
        givenName = oETextN.getText().toString();
        givenPhNum = oETextPh.getText().toString();
        OrgiOperations.Insert2Contacts(getApplicationContext(),
                givenName, givenPhNum);
        if (OrgiOperations.isTheNumberExistsinContacts(
                getApplicationContext(), givenPhNum)) {
            Log.i(OrgiOperations.TAG, "Exists");
        } else {
            Log.i(OrgiOperations.TAG, "Not Exists");
        }

    }

});
}
```

Comment: What I'm about to ask might be vague but due to my low android experience, where am I supposed to put the onclicklistener method then?

Comment: @user3050101 after initialization of views inside a method

Comment: please be more specific for this could solve my answer right in a second (:

Comment: @user3050101 i posted a code snippet what more specific do you want?. follow what is suggested in the post it will work

Comment: I was actually talking about the onclicklistener .. I did exactly as said the application now runs! (: but now after filling the fields when I press the save button the application again force closes

Comment: @user3050101 i also mentioned the same in my post. post the stacktrace and the relevant `activity_main.xml`. :( and what is `OrgiOperations`